# Why isn't my jsp page loading after trying to access it in a MVC Controller class in my Spring Application

Tags: javascript, jsp, spring-mvc

I'm trying to load a value into a JSP page (`houseprice.jsp`) based on information provided by a user on another JSP page (index.jsp). Basically, a user will provide an address which will be converted (on the client side) to a latitude and a longitude value on index.jsp. These two double values will then be passed to my controller class (via an AJAX JQuery) so I can run a method that will query a PostgreSQL database to return an average house price of all the houses within a 1km radius of the original latitude and longitude.

Everything is working perfectly i.e. the latitude and longitude values pass from the client side to the controller, the method is run, the database gets queried successfully. I have a simple println debugger that prints everything successfully in the eclipse console. The only issue is the `houseprice` jsp page won't load after everything else correctly runs.

HousePriceParser method in Controller class

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/parseHousePrice", method={RequestMethod.POST, RequestMethod.GET})
public @ResponseBody String parseHousePrice(HousePrice housePrice, @RequestParam("latitude") double latitude,@RequestParam("longitude") double longitude, Model model) {

    // Running method that queries PostgreSQL for average price
    double housePriceAverage = parseHousePrice.ParseHousePrice(latitude, longitude);

    // Adding results from PostgreSQL db to array to get number of houses
    List<Double> housePriceList = parseHousePrice.getList();
    int housePriceListSize = housePriceList.size();

    // Simple println  debugger
    System.out.println("The average house price for this area is: " + housePriceAverage + " based on " + housePriceListSize + " property prices in this area");

    // Im trying to pass the two values calculated above to houseprice.jsp
    model.addAttribute("houseprice", housePriceAverage);
    model.addAttribute("housepricelistsize", housePriceListSize);

    // Page I'm trying to load but wont load
    return "houseprice";
}
```

I'm calling the function on the javascript side with the AJAX JQuery via a tab in a navbar that looks like this

```
<li><a onclick = "parseHousePrice();" >House Price</a></li>
```

And the javascript function is written like this

```
function parseHousePrice(){

       $('.search_latitude').val(marker.getPosition().lat());
       var Lat = marker.getPosition().lat();
       console.log(Lat);

       $('.search_longitude').val(marker.getPosition().lng());
       var Long = marker.getPosition().lng();
       console.log(Long);

    $.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url: "/parseHousePrice",
     data: { latitude: Lat, 
          longitude: Long,  
    }, // parameters
 datatype: 'json'
});

    }
```

Comment: try removing @responsebody annotation

Comment: That didn't fix it but thank you for the answer. I've updated the question with a bit more information if that helps.

Comment: If you use @ResponseBody, "houseprice" is not considered as a jsp page but just a string. So If you want make a ajax operation then return model directly i.e. "return housePriceAverage" instead of "houseprice". And parse it in the ajax success callback.